# Web server transaction vs DB trigger - which is preferred?

Tags: php, mysql, database, rdbms

I would like to ask you for a situation that each value of two tables must be changed at the same time.

There are two ways of the above, Web server transaction, DB trigger.

Web server transaction is 100% safe? I am worried about a situation like one value of one table has been changed but another value of another table has not.

I think DB trigger is safer than Web server transaction, but I use both of them due to the worries above.

Also, I would like to ask you about DB procedure. Is it preferred? I prefer to use php codes and don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions exist to solve EXACTLY the problem you describe. Either all queries within the transaction succeed, or the database is rolled back as if nothing ever happened.

While I'm sure there are people who would disagree with me, I am not a fan of using triggers or stored procedures to create program logic. Not because of safety, but because triggers become hidden code, not in your version control system (unless you are diligent with migrations), adding logic to a query that you can't see when you read the source code.

And what about error handling? What will you do if your trigger fails?

Think of the next person who will be working on your code, even if that person is you, two years from now. Simplicity and clarity will always pay.